# Use webflux WebClient to publish a sink of a flux of objects

Tags: spring-webflux

So I have a Flux of objects like this:

```
MyObject o1 = new MyObject("publish", "one");
MyObject o2 = new MyObject("publish", "two");
MyObject o3 = new MyObject("publish", "three");

Flux<Object> myFlux = Flux.just(o1, o2, o3);
```

I want to post the flux to an endpoint through a default webClient like this:

```
public Flux<String> publishFlux(Flux<Object> events) {
    return eventClient.post()
        .uri(env.getProperty(BASE))
        .body(events, Object.class)
        .exchangeToFlux(resp -> resp.bodyToFlux(String.class));
}
```

I am trying to use a `Sinks.Many()` but I don't know how to get the flux objects published. I am trying something like this.

```
Many<Object> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
sink.tryEmitNext(myFlux);
publishFlux(sink.asFlux()).subscribe();
```

or something like this:

```
Many<Object> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
value.subscribe(x -> sink.tryEmitNext(x));
publishFlux(sink.asFlux()).subscribe();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide more details about API you want publish your flux to? Is it accept array of events or single event?

Comment: First of all, you need a subscriber already waiting on your sink, because you use a "directBestEffort" sink (its apidoc states: `Without Subscriber: fail fast on tryEmitNext.`). So, in both your snippets, `publishFlux(sink.asFlux().subscribe());` should be called **before** trying to emit values in sink. Also, you should **always** check tryEmit return value anyway. Value emission in sinks can fail for various reasons . And, lastly, it is not clear to me why you try to use a sink here. Sinks are for corner-cases where you have a livestream/hot flux of data to map as reactive stream.